# Android studio import project complaining about jar files.

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to set up an existing `Android Studio` project on a new machine on and `Android studio`. Its complaining about the following jar when I try to run the app

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/username/Documents/workspace/Android2/app/libs/simmetrics_jar_v1_6_2_d07_02_07.jar (No such file or directory)

What does it need this for and how can i resolve it?

I use parse server and twitter fabric in the project.

Comment: Just a note, you should use Gradle Dependencies for Parse and Twitter instead of Jar files as this solve a lot of issues. Just add the lines to the dependencies block in your app-level `build.gradle`. Not sure about Twitter Fabric, but **Parse:** `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'` and delete the .jar files you added for parse.

Comment: @AbAppletic that's what I have`compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'`
    `compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'`

Comment: @AbAppletic, Thanks, Your comment did help. I had an extra library referenced in my Gradle  :).